# Curl get other website instead requested

Tags: php, curl

I try load page http://ars-sps.ru/all-contact via php CURL, but in result CURL return webpage http://legaljapan.jp.

How can it be?

PHP code:

```
    $headers = array(
        'Expect:',
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9',
        'Accept-Language: ru,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.7',
        'Accept-Charset: utf-8,windows-1251;q=0.7,*;q=0.5',
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://ars-sps.ru/all-contact' );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 80);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.1.1) Gecko/20090716 Ubuntu/9.04 (jaunty) Shiretoko/3.5.1');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 2); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 7); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'curl_cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'curl_cookie.txt');

    echo $page = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: So if you open http://ars-sps.ru/all-contact in browser it redirects you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use "CURLOPT_USERAGENT" param then.

Comment: Thanks, helped. But I don't understand why?

Comment: here i put "CURLOPT_USERAGENT" as following and worked in your code
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1) Gecko/20090622 Ubuntu/9.04 (jaunty) Shiretoko/3.5');

I think the server is redirecting you because your USERAGENT have problem.

Comment: Inside you user agent param change "Linux x86_64" to matching one.